# How to export dataframe to csv using conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am merging data using different data sets and appending them in one single dataset. The problem is that sometimes dataset `df_fours` is empty. To deal with this I have used `try` and `pass` statements.

Now when `df_fours_unique` is bypassed and when I try to export the results in CSV it gives the error:

```
df_append3 is not defined
```

What I want is to have some conditional statement (or if there is something else) which will export `df_append3` if it doesn't have any error. Otherwise it will just append `df_append2`. What I currently have is:

```
df_unique = pd.merge(df7,df6_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_twos = pd.merge(df9,df8_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_twos_unique = df_twos[df_twos.index % 2 == 0]
df_threes = pd.merge(df11,df10_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_threes_unique = df_threes[df_threes.index % 3 == 0]
try:
    df_fours = pd.merge(df13,df12_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
    df_fours_unique = df_fours[df_fours.index % 4 == 0]
except:
    pass
df_append1 = df_unique.append(df_twos_unique)
df_append2 = df_append1.append(df_threes_unique)
try:
    df_append3 = df_append2.append(df_fours_unique)
except: 
    pass 
df_append3.to_csv('export.csv')
```

Couldn't attach the datasets due to confidentiality.

Comment: *"Couldn't attach the datasets due to confidentiality."* - so just post a [mre]...

Comment: Can you ensure that the indentation of the code you've provided above matches what you're *actually* working with? Python is an indent-sensitive language, and differing indentation levels change how the script is interpreted/executed.

Comment: Anyway, your definition of `df_append3` is inside a `try` block so if there is an error it will not be defined... Move to the `to_csv` line to be in the `try` as well...

Comment: First off, you should fix your indentation. Its important in python. Second you only define `df_append3` in one of your try statements so if theres an issue there it wont be defined. A simple `if no error df_append3 else df_append2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to have some conditional statement (or if there is
> something else) which will export df_append3 if it doesn't have any
> error. Otherwise it will just append df_append2.

There is, and you're alrady using it! It's called `try/except`... If there was no error (inside the `try`) - add `df_append3`. Otherwise (`except`), append `df_append2`:

```py
try:
    df_append3 = df_append2.append(df_fours_unique)
    df_append3.to_csv('export.csv')
except: 
    df_append2.to_csv('export.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html

```
if not df_fours.empty:
    #The dataframe is not empty, we can write it
```

and by same token

```
if not df_append3.empty:
    #can write this too...
```

Better approach than try: except: I'd think.